# How can I connect to a docker container using its name instead of its IP address?

Tags: linux, unix, docker, containers, ping

How can I connect to a docker container using its name instead of its IP address using the ping command?

```
ping <container_name> instead of ping <IP_address>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`Network-scoped alias`](https://github.com/mavenugo/docker/blob/dda513ef651b42fcb9625e651f664554161c0a6a/docs/userguide/networking/work-with-networks.md#network-scoped-alias). It allows you to ping a container by its name.

Answer (score 1):

`ping $(docker inspect -f {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}} <container_name>)`